# Save variable to compare in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to modify this code so that when the name of the same song is displayed +10 min in the DOM of my html it is modified by a custom name.

This happens because the software I use to broadcast on the radio does not allow me to send metadata, so when I start broadcasting the static name of the last song played by the radio automatic is displayed.

I've tried several ideas with *setInterval* and *setTimeout* functions but I can't find a way to save the song's name displayed in the html in a variable so that I can compare it with the one I get in the ajax of the *Nowplaying* function.

```
window.onload = function() {

  var page = new Page;
  page.changeTitlePage();
  page.setVolume();

  var player = new Player();
  player.play();

  NowPlaying();

  // Interval to get streaming data in miliseconds

  // Update every 5 seconds
  setInterval(function() {
    NowPlaying();
  }, 5000);

  var coverArt = document.getElementsByClassName('cover-album')[0];
  coverArt.style.height = coverArt.offsetWidth + 'px';

}
// Get current song
function NowPlaying() {
  $.ajax({
    url: PROXYURL + URL_STREAMING3,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(result) {
      if (result.trim() !== '') {
        $("#currentSong").html(result);
      } else {
        $("#currentSong").html('DJ OsiriS in Session');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see in the last function, if the result I get with the *GET* is an empty string, the phrase 'DJ OsiriS in Session' is placed in the currentSong ID of my html.
I want to do the same thing if the displayed song name remains "static" for 10 minutes.
Any other information you need, or the HTML code let me know and I'll gladly share it.

I await your kind comments so that I can learn to perform this task.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of the problem and a specific programming question?

Comment: What I want is that if that song that the GET (see NowPlaying function code) gets has the same name for 10 minutes, I change it to the phrase "DJ OsiriS in Session". If you look at that function, it is contemplated that that phrase is put if the name of the song is empty, there you should add an OR and add something that counts the 10 minutes and if it is the same, go to ELSE. But I can't save the data in a variable because it would be overwritten by what was obtained in the GET.

Comment: Why can't you store the name and a timestamp in a variable? I don't understand your problem. What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use global variables to hold the last title and when it was first received. If the new title is different, show it and reset the timestamp. Otherwise, check if the current time is more than 10 minutes since the timestamp.

```js
var lastTitle, lastTitleTime;

// Get current song
function NowPlaying() {
  $.ajax({
    url: PROXYURL + URL_STREAMING3,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(result) {
      let title = result.trim();
      if (title !== '') {
        if (title !== lastTitle) {
          lastTitle = title;
          lastTitleTime = Date.now();
        } else if (Date.now() > lastTitleTime + 10 * 60 * 1000) {
          title = 'DJ Osiris in Session';
        }
      } else {
        title = 'DJ Osiris in Session';
      }
      $("#currentSong").html(title);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, you have solved the code and I thank you very much.
Humble people like you are the ones who demonstrate their knowledge and not like others who don't know or don't read the problem well and are dedicated to giving negative votes.